# Is there a different way to write this that wont throw an error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-7, internet-explorer-8

This line is throwing an error in IE8 on Windows 7, in all our testing on BrowserStack it is the only browser throwing the error.

Here is the whole block of code...

```
jQuery('.quoter_steps .loading_rates').slideDown('fast', function () {
     jQuery('.quoter_steps .loading_rates').prepend(jQuery('<p>', { class: 'error_message' }).append(vals));
     jQuery(".error_message").css("display", "block");
     jQuery("p.error_message").css("display", "block");
     jQuery(".quoter_contain").removeClass("step_two--on");
     jQuery(".quoter_contain").addClass("step_three--on");
});
```

This is the one line that is causing a problem:

```
jQuery('.quoter_steps .loading_rates').prepend(jQuery('<p>', { class: 'error_message' }).append(vals));
```

The error starts at "class:" and says `"Expected identifier, string or number"`

No other browser errors on this line and it is an outdated browser but our business still shows a bit of traffic from this browser that we don't want to just serve up a page with an error. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Try `{ "class": 'error_message' }`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could always just use this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('quoter_steps');
el[0].insertBefore(elChild, el.firstChild);
```

Assuming that the .loading_rates class is the first and probably only element withing .quoter_steps

Reference [this](http://clubmate.fi/append-and-prepend-elements-with-pure-javascript/) article for specifics.

For older browsers specifically it's good to try to not rely on Jquery too much.